# Transform an imported list between brackets to a list between parentheses

Tags: input

I'm using Macaulay2 to make some computations and export a text.txt file which contains a list of numbers, in the form of, for example, {1,2,3}.

I further want to input that list into my tex file, but I need it to be between normal parentheses. It's to be used by the "yng" command from the youngtab package.

So I want my tex file to do \yng(1,2,3), but I don't know how to do that because if I do \input{text.txt} I'll get {1,2,3}: I don't want those brackets there.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: It also seems that Steven saw further ahead than me what I will want to do in the future! As a further step, if I can input a text file which has one such list per line, and LaTeX makes the Young tableaux out of each line automatically, it'll be great.

Comment: So you *only* have (say) `{1,2,3}` in `text.txt`, nothing else?

Comment: @Werner: precisely!

Comment: @Werner: Steven's answer made me realize that *actually*, I *will* be using text files that have several such lines (and nothing else). Please see my edits above, thanks!

Comment: If you're creating the file, instead of writing `{1,2,3}`, can you write `\something{1,2,3}`?

Comment: @Werner: yes, I could do that.

Comment: Because, at that stage you can easily do `\newcommand{\something}[1]{\yng(#1)}` and just `\input{temp.txt}` within your document, rather than having to use a package to capture the file, then process the file sequentially...

Comment: @Werner: I see. I've never written a "for" loop in LaTeX -- if you could modify your answer to make code that would read such a file and automatically make the tableaux for all the lines, that'd be greatly appreciated. Hopefully I'll learn out of that how to make a loop for future use :)

Comment: I've added something to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `text.txt` file has multiple entries, one per record, then this allows one to access them as array elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab,readarray}
\newcommand\yngalt[1]{%
  \def\tmpA{\yng(}%
  \edef\tmpB{#1}%
  \expandafter\tmpA\tmpB)%
}
\begin{filecontents*}{text.txt}
{1,2,3}
{2,3,4}
{4,1,3,5}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readrecordarray{text.txt}\myyng
3rd entry: \yngalt{\myyng[3]}

2nd entry: \yngalt{\myyng[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there will always be only one braced list in the `text.txt` file, here is an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab,readarray}
\newcommand\yngalt[1]{%
  \readdef{text.txt}\myyng
  \expandafter\yngaltaux\myyng }
\def\yngaltaux#1 {\yng(#1)}
\begin{filecontents*}{text.txt}
{4,1,3,5}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
THE entry: \yngalt{text.txt}
\end{document}
```

**SUPPLEMENT**

Handle it with a loop over all entries in the file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab,readarray}
\newcommand\yngalt[1]{%
  \def\tmp{\yng(}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp#1)}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{text.txt}
{1,2,3}
{2,3,4}
{4,1,3,5}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{text.txt}\myyngdata
\readlist*\myyng{\myyngdata}

Loop:\\
\foreachitem\z\in\myyng[]{\ifnum\zcnt=1\else
  \the\numexpr\zcnt-1\relax: 
  \yngalt{\myyng[\zcnt-1]}\\[3pt]\fi}

2nd entry: \yngalt{\myyng[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! Your several-lines approach made me realize I actually need that. Could you see my edit of the OP?

Comment: @BrunoStonek Please see my supplement.

Answer (score 2):

Using `catchfile` as suggested by Werner, but with a twist:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.yt}
{1,2,3}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\yngfile}[1]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\yngfiledef}{#1}{}%
  \expandafter\makeyngfile\yngfiledef
}
\newcommand{\makeyngfile}[1]{\yng(#1)}

\begin{document}

\yngfile{\jobname-1.yt}

\end{document}
```

Thus you can have as many files as you want. However, this would read the disk any time you need the same tableau.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.yt}
{1,2,3}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\yngfile}[1]{%
  \ifcsname yngfiledef@#1\endcsname
    % the file has already been loaded
  \else
  \CatchFileDef\temporaryyngfile{#1}{}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname yngfiledef@#1\endcsname\temporaryyngfile
  \fi
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\makeyngfile\csname yngfiledef@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\makeyngfile}[1]{\yng(#1)}

\begin{document}

\yngfile{\jobname-1.yt}\quad\yngfile{\jobname-1.yt}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this with the `-recorder` option, I see that the file is loaded just once.

[image]

The `expl3` version:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.yt}
{1,2,3}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\yngfile}{m}
 {
  \stonek_yngfile:n { #1 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_stonek_yngfile_prop
\tl_new:N \l__stonek_yngfile_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonek_yngfile:n
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnF \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 }
   {% the file has not yet been read in
    \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l__stonek_yngfile_tmp_tl
    \prop_gput:Nnx \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 }
     {
      \exp_last_unbraced:NV \__stonek_yngfile_fix:n \l__stonek_yngfile_tmp_tl
     }
   }
  \prop_item:Nn \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__stonek_yngfile_fix:n { \exp_not:N \yng(#1) }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\yngfile{\jobname-1.yt}\quad\yngfile{\jobname-1.yt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the contents of a file into a macro using [`catchfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) (into `\temp`, say), then trim the braces by using it as an argument to another macro and replace it with parentheses with the following

```
\def\tempa#1{\def\temp{(#1)}}% Add parentheses around #1
\expandafter\tempa\temp% Update \temp
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{temp.txt}
{1,2,3}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{catchfile,youngtab}

% \CatchFileDef{<cmd>}{<file>}{<setup>}
\CatchFileDef{\temp}{temp.txt}{}
\def\tempa#1{\def\temp{(#1)}}% Macro to add parentheses around #1
\expandafter\tempa\temp% Update \temp

\begin{document}

\expandafter\yng\temp

\end{document}
```

---

Since you're writing the source file `temp.txt`, you may as well include whatever LaTeX commands you need as part of the output. For example, outputting

```
\something{1,2,3}
\something{4,1,3,2}
\something{1,3,5,7}
% ...and so on...
```

allows you to have a LaTeX "hook" (or macro) attached to each "table sequence". Now you can add

```
\newcommand{\something}[1]{\yng(#1)}
```

in your preamble and just call

```
\input{temp.txt}
```

within your document where you want *all* the tables within `temp.txt` to appear. That is, there's no need to cycle through each element one-by-one and print it, since `\input` will just throw the entire file in the input stream.

If you need a vertical gap between tables, perhaps use

```
\newcommand{\something}[1]{\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}\yng(#1)}
```