# Loading a file with special characters for use with readrecordarray

Tags: input

I'm using `readrecordarray` as in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/582975/1403 but I want to include files whose filenames have special characters: underscores, commas and brackets. These files are automatically generated by another program, and it's convenient for me to load them as-is without renaming them.

How can I achieve this?

Example: the filename is `file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt`

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: @egreg: Done, thanks.

Comment: So it is the file name having special characters?

Comment: @egreg: Indeed! Sorry, that was unclear. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of my answer to your previous question, which accepts arbitrary file names and allows for the syntax

```
\yngfile[<number>]{<filename>}
```

where the optional argument (default 1) refers to the line number in the file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}
{1,2,3}
{2,3,4}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\yngfile}{O{1}m}
 {
  \stonek_yngfile:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_stonek_yngfile_prop
\tl_new:N \l__stonek_yngfile_tmp_tl
\ior_new:N \g__stonek_yngfile_ior
\int_new:N \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonek_yngfile:nn
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__stonek_yngfile_ior { #2 }
  \prop_if_in:NnF \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #2 }
   {
    \prop_gput:Nxx \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #2 } { } % just a marker
    \int_zero:N \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__stonek_yngfile_ior
     {% the file has not yet been read in
      \int_incr:N \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int
      \prop_gput:Nxx \g_stonek_yngfile_prop
       {
        #2 @ \int_to_arabic:n { \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int }
       }
       {
        \__stonek_yngfile_fix:n ##1
       }
     }
   }
  \prop_item:Ne \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #2 @ #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__stonek_yngfile_fix:n { \exp_not:N \yng(#1) }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\yngfile[1]{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}\quad
\yngfile[2]{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}

\end{document}
```

Like the previous answer, this allows for reusing the tableaux without rereading the file each time. When the file name is found the first time, a property list is populated with the data in the form `\yng(<line contents without braces>)`, so you can call the tableau without further disk access wherever you want.

[image]

An improved version where `\yngfile*{<filename>}` prints all the diagrams with a `\quad` separation between them.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}
{1,2,3}
{2,3,4}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\yngfile}{sO{1}m}
 {
  \stonek_yngfile_process:n { #3 } % store the diagrams, if needed
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \stonek_yngfile_print_all:n { #3 }
   }
   {
    \stonek_yngfile_print_one:nn { #3 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_stonek_yngfile_prop
\tl_new:N \l__stonek_yngfile_tmp_tl
\ior_new:N \g__stonek_yngfile_ior
\int_new:N \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonek_yngfile_process:n
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__stonek_yngfile_ior { #1 }
  \prop_if_in:NnF \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 }
   {
    \int_zero:N \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__stonek_yngfile_ior
     {% the file has not yet been read in
      \int_incr:N \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int
      \prop_gput:Nxx \g_stonek_yngfile_prop
       {
        #1 @ \int_to_arabic:n { \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int }
       }
       {
        \__stonek_yngfile_fix:n ##1
       }
     }
    % store the number of tableaux
    \prop_gput:Nxx \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 }
     {
      \int_to_arabic:n { \l__stonek_yngfile_index_int }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__stonek_yngfile_fix:n { \exp_not:N \yng(#1) }

\cs_new:Nn \stonek_yngfile_print_one:nn
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 @ #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stonek_yngfile_print_all:n
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { \prop_item:Nn \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 } }
   {
    \prop_item:Nn \g_stonek_yngfile_prop { #1 @ ##1 }\quad
   }
   \unskip
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\yngfile[1]{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}

\yngfile*{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}

\yngfile[2]{file_7_{1,2,3},{2,3,4}.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would there be a way for the code to automatically make the tableaux for all the lines in the text file? i.e. without having to specify [1], then [2], then [3]...

Comment: @BrunoStonek Easy! ;-) New version online.

Comment: Unrelatedly, another request if you don't mind... I should have noticed this earlier, sorry. Some of my files will be named something like young_a_b_{1,2,3}_{2,3,4}.txt  where a<b are integers. So if a=2 and b=5, the txt will consist of 4 entries, from 2 to 5. Would it be possible for the automatically generated tableaux to be labeled in order according to these numbers? Thank you so much.

Comment: To clarify, I expect to be handling two types of files: one is of the form young_a_{1,2,3}_{2,3,4}.txt  and has only one entry, the other is of the form young_a_b_{1,2,3}_{2,3,4}.txt and has a range of entries (from a to b).

Comment: @BrunoStonek What do you mean by “labeled”?

Comment: A printed name for the tableaux, displayed next to each one of them.

Comment: @BrunoStonek Please, make a followup question with ***all*** the details. For instance, are you going to reuse the tableaux? If not, much of my code turns out to be unneeded. Also, ***how*** should the label be printed? What's the format of the files you want to read? Here I assume they have a tableau specification per line, but that's never explicitly said in your questions.

Comment: I've gave it further thought and I think it's fine as it is now. Sorry I've been so unclear and incomplete. And once more: thanks!